# How to edit URL after a button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, symfony

My web application is an `Employee task manager` where tasks can be created and they have states (`INIT`,`IN-PROGRESS`,`COMPLETED`) the states will be changed upon actions (`Add`,`complete`)

[image]

When I click "Add" button, the URL is `viewEmployeeTaskList/empNumber/4`
 I input some data and click save button.(`CREATE`) .Then the input form fields will be hidden and the record will be displayed in the table below.

[image]

Next I click the the link to that entry from the list table. 
There new button appears
[image]

Then th URL becomes `viewEmployeeTaskList/empNumber/4/id/1`

But when I click "Add" adain, the URL remains as `viewEmployeeTaskList/empNumber/4/id/1` But I want to `remove the id` from the URL. Any idea?
Here is my JavaScript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search-results').removeClass('box');

    $('.actionable-buttons').click(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');
        $('#emptasks_action').val(action);
        $('#frmEmpTaskManager').submit();
    });

    $('#btnSaveTask').click(function() {
        $('#frmEmpTaskManager').submit();
    });

    $("#frmEmpTaskManager").validate({
        rules: {
            'emptasks[task_name]': {required: true},
            'emptasks[description]' : {maxlength:1000},
            'emptasks[due_date]' : {valid_date: function(){
                return {format:datepickerDateFormat,
                        required:false,
                        displayFormat:displayDateFormat
                };
            }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'emptasks[task_name]': {required: lang_taskNameRequired},
            'emptasks[description]': {maxlength: lang_descriptionLength},
            'emptasks[due_date]' : {valid_date: lang_invalidDate}
        }

    });

    if(!(haveTasks)) {
        $(".check").hide();
    }

    if($('#emptasks_id').val()==''){
        $('#addEmployeeTask').hide();
    }else{
        $('#addEmployeeTask').show();
    }

    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        $('#addEmployeeTask').show();
        clearAddForm();
        $('#search-results').find('div.top').hide();
    });

    $('#btnCancel').click(function() {
        clearAddForm();
        $('#addEmployeeTask').hide();
        $('#search-results').find('div.top').show();
    });

    $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $("#ohrmList_chkSelectAll").click(function() {
        if ($(":checkbox").length == 1) {
            $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
            if ($("#ohrmList_chkSelectAll").is(':checked')) {
                $('#btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    });
    $(':checkbox[name*="chkSelectRow[]"]').click(function() {
        if ($(':checkbox[name*="chkSelectRow[]"]').is(':checked')) {
            $('#btnDelete').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#btnDelete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });

    $('#dialogDeleteBtn').click(function() {
        document.frmList_ohrmListComponent.submit();
    });

    $('#btnDelete').click(function() {
        $('#deletePopUpMessenger').click();
    });

    $('#dialogDeleteBtn').click(function() {
        document.frmList_ohrmListComponent.submit();
    });


    function clearAddForm() {
        $('#emptasks_id').val('');
        $('#emptasks_task_name').val('');
        $('#emptasks_description').val('');
        $('#emptasks_due_date').val('');
        $('div#addEmployeeTask label.error').hide();
        $('div#messagebar').hide();
    }


});
```

Comment: Hide the complete Button. Use $('#completeBtn').hide(); assuming the id of the complete button.

Comment: The add and edit modal is the same or different modals? If the same I can't see the part of the code what is shows the complete button. Where is the part when you clicks to an existent task and shows edit modal?

Comment: Hi @ChandrasekarG, I t worked. Now I have a different problem. Please see my updated question.

Comment: You can hide the Complete button at documents.ready function. and enable the button when clicking link as well as again hide the Complete button when clicking the cancel button.